# Java Client Server - Exception Handling (Thread)

Tags: java, exception, server, client

I wonder how to handle exceptions correctly within a client server application. My client sends an information to the server(thread) which receives it within its run method.
I have already read something about uncaught exception handling when dealing with exceptions in the run method but want to know if this is the correct way to do it in my case.
I want to catch the exception on the client side.

I have in mind to do the following:

```
//Server

run(){
  try{
...
  }
  catch(Exception e){
     clientoutputstream.write(...); //transmitting the error
  }
}
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You have to consider what happens when the other end disconnects unexpectedly, you won't be able to write an error message to it. i.e. send an error message if you can, but you should handle the case where this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a try { } catch (IOException) around your read() call so you know if the other end has closed the connection. The other thing you might want to do is to put a try { } catch(Throwable) { } around the processing code so you can manually close the socket (Be very careful about catching Throwable) But if you just let the thread die the Socket will be closed when the object is garbage collected or when it times out